# Dynamic DNS on D-Link DWR-112 3G router uses a private IP address

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, dynamic-dns

I'm using a D-Link DWR-112 3G router to connect to the internet by using Celcom broadband plug-in.

How can I do the port forwarding to my server? I already have correctly configured my DynDNS, but every time the DynDNS will not set to public address but local private address with in the range 10.xxx.xxx.xxx. My router address is 192.168.1.1 and server address is 192.168.1.5.

Can someone give me some guideline about this issue?

Comment: Is the WAN IP of your router on the 10.x.x.x range?

Comment: Like @CyberJacob said, if its not you can always change your WAN settings within the router to be on the required range.

Comment: @CyberJacob the public ip start from 203.xx.xxx.xxx

Comment: @Ash King can you some me some step to change the WAN Setting?

Comment: • Login to your (192.168.1.1 - user: admin pass: {blank}) • Go to advanced, then there should be a link to WAN settings somewhere. Hard to tell without knowing the router gateway. What you want to do is change it from the 192 range to the 10. range.

Comment: @AshKing: Changing the WAN IP address without cooperation with the ISP will break the connectivity! The IP range beginning with `10` is a private range too. So this will not help.

Comment: Agree with pabouk. i have configure the DynDns, however, the dyndns always with ip address start with 10. that is no problem for me to use dyndns to remote desktop port forwarding 3389 with the same network, but it now allow me to remote desktop from outside network. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately D-Link routers contain only a simple dynamic DNS agent which directly uses IP address from the WAN interface without checking if it is public or not. In your case you are using a directly connected USB 3G modem so you are already using the IP address you get from your ISP. The ISP is performing NAT (address translation) of the private IP address to the public IP address which you can see by using [What Is My IP](http://www.whatismyip.com/) or similar services.

Unfortunately you cannot simply change the WAN IP address without breaking the connectivity. Additionally there is another possible problem. If the ISP is performing a dynamic NAT (also called hide NAT or PAT) dynamic DNS alone will not allow you to enable incoming connections to you from the Internet.

There are two basic possibilities:

- Ask your ISP if they can assign a public IP address to your WAN interface. (Of course the address does not need to be static.)
- Use a more sophisticated dynamic DNS agent / update client which will discover your real public IP address a similar way like What Is My IP works. You will have to run the agent on a computer in your network. DynDNS has its own [Dyn Update Clients](http://dyn.com/support/clients/).

Comment: So, there is actually no way to find the public IP on my D-link routers WAN interface?

Comment: @Kangkan: The question was about something different. There are ways how to manually find out what is your public IP address (which does not need to be the IP address of the WAN interface). You can use for example http://www.whatismyip.com/ on a computer on the internal interface or WiFi of the router.

Comment: Got it. So I shall have to update the IP every time I connect the router after I disconnect or update the IP whenever the IP changes (I do not have a static IP), right?

Comment: @Kangkan: Yes, every time you (re)connect the router's WAN interface or you (re)start the router your public IP address can change. --- If you want your dynamic public IP address to be accessible from the internet over a constant domain name you can use [dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) and this is what the question was about.

Comment: I understood the question and I am using the DynamicDNS feature in the router. However, if I visit the ddns site, I see the private IP (10.x.x.x) on the router WAN interface registered there.

Comment: @Kangkan: The second solution in my reply says that you can run dynamic DNS agent on your PC instead on the router. This should solve your problem.